# How to insert unit with Siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I simply want to insert a unit in my document how should I use this package?
Where can I find this information in the user manual?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The velocity is \SI{10}{\metre\per\second} and 
the units are \unit{\metre\per\second}.
\end{document}
```

With this example I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 the units are \unit
                       {\metre\per\second}.
```

Comment: According to the index at the end of the currrent edition of user guide document, the `\unit` macro occurs on pages 3, 6, 7, 10, 14, 34, and 52. However, it looks like you're using an older TeX distribution -- or, at least, one that hasn't been brought up to date for a year or more. With older versions of the `siunitx` package, use `\si` instead of `\unit`.

Comment: See §3.3 (units, p.5-7) in the documentation. Since version 3, you should use `\qty`,  not `\SI`.

Comment: @Bernard but unfortunately it doesn't work with `texlive-full` on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is your version up-to-date?

Comment: you are using syntax of siunitx version 3, the ubuntu texlive may still be on siunitx version 2, check your log file

Comment: @Bernard, I don't know how to check that, and as I build the project over a Docker container, I prefer to use the base version of the Ubuntu 20.04 distribution.

Comment: the version 2 syntax would be `\si` rather than `\unit`

Comment: If you compile `\listfiles\documentclass{article}\usepackage{siunitx}\begin{document}a\end{document}` the `.log` file will contain a list of the packages and their versions, that would be one way of figuring out which version you have.

Comment: @nowox, the stock version of Ubuntu 20.04 is TexLive 2019 --- so the packages are several years old now --- your `siunitx` is version 2 for sure, probably `siunitx 2020/01/15 v2.7u`. So you need to use `\SI{}{}` and `\si{}`.

Comment: You should be able to open the `siunitx` documentation of the version installed on your system by executing `texdoc siunitx`.